# SSDT 2017 drops variables from script task after importing a project

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, etl

I have SSDT 2017 installed and I needed to import a SSIS project from SSIS server. Project contains around 10 packages. Import was fine, but after opening a package (actually, I've checked all of them), script task lost ReadOnly and ReadWrite variables:

[image: see the snapshot]

The script itself if fine.

Can you guys help? Is it a bug?